# Magento 2.2.2 - Class not found in Factory

Tags: event-observer, class, object-manager, factory

**Namespace/Modulename/Model/WebService/ClientFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\WebService;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\WebService\Config;


class ClientFactory
{

    protected $config;


    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return \Modulename\WebService\Client
     */
    public function create(array $data = [])
    {
        if (isset($data['options']) && is_string($data['options'])) {
            $data['options'] = ['host' => $data['options']];
        } elseif (empty($data['options'])) {
            $data['options'] = [];
        }

        $userId = !empty($data['userId']) ? $data['userId'] : $this->config->getUserId();
        $licenseKey = !empty($data['licenseKey']) ? $data['licenseKey'] : $this->config->getLicenseKey();
        $locales = !empty($data['locales']) ? $data['locales'] : ['en'];
        $options = $data['options'] + ['host' => $this->config->getHost()];

        $client = new \Modulename\WebService\Client($userId, $licenseKey, $locales, $options);
        return $client;
    }
}
```

**Namespace/Modulename/Observer/Redirect.php**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\WebService\Config;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\WebService\ClientFactory;

class Redirect implements ObserverInterface {


    protected $clientFactory;


    public function __construct(Config $config, ClientFactory $clientFactory)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->clientFactory = $clientFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) 
    {

        $client = $this->clientFactory->create();
        $record = $client->city('128.101.101.101');
        print($record->country->isoCode . "\n");        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Modulename\WebService\Client' not
>   found in Namespace/Modulename/Model/WebService/ClientFactory.php

Comment: what is this line means $client = new \Modulename\WebService\Client($userId, $licenseKey, $locales, $options);

Comment: This will instantiate the object. For example `
$client = new Client(42, 'abcdef123456');`. This creates a Client object that can be reused across requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory classes are generated by magento itself, you don't need to create it manually.

Just rename your class to **Client** and magento would fetch **ClientFactory** by itself.

Comment: Does that mean if I change `new \Modulename\WebService\Client` to `new \Modulename\WebService\ClientFactory`, should it work?

Comment: yes, it should work.

Comment: If I rename file back to `ClientFactory.php` and change code to `Class ClientFactory and new \Modulename\WebService\ClientFactory` it thorws exception `Source class "\Modulename\WebService\Client" for "Modulename\WebService\ClientFactory" generation does not exist.`

Comment: You should just keep a single class file that is client , ClientFactory is generated by magento.You should not worry about it.

Comment: Okay but now it says Class `Modulename\WebService\Client not found in Namespace/Modulename/Model/WebService/Client`. Should there be change in `Observer/Redirect.php` as well?

Comment: I think you messed up namespace , there should be model directory in it too.

Comment: Indeed there is a `Model` directory but do you mean `$client = new \GeoIp\WebService\Client($userId, $licenseKey, $locales, $options);` should be `$client = new \GeoIp\Model\WebService\Client($userId, $licenseKey, $locales, $options);`?

Comment: It should be where the Client class is located ,according to question it should be  $client = new \GeoIp\WebService\Model\Client($userId, $licenseKey, $locales, $options);

Comment: Also you should use dependency injection to add classes.

Comment: Please ask a separate question for it, this thread is gone too long as it is. Also if it helped please accept the answer and consider +1.